# CKEditor 4.7x - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to get the imageuploader working with CKeditor and I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer load_ckeditor.js
```

Here is the contents of_ckeditor.js

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 
      'imageuploader', 
       '/themes/blog/imageuploader/', 
       'plugin.js' 
);

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{
    extraPlugins = 'imageuploader'
});
```

The error line number refers to this:

```
extraPlugins = 'imageuploader'
```

I have copied the code exactly per the example here: https://cdn.ckeditor.com/

When I remove, extraPlugins = 'imageuploader', the CKEditor loads properly but it is missing the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in your syntax, `CKEDITOR.replace` takes an object so it requires a colon not an equals.  The correct implementation should be:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{
  extraPlugins: 'imageuploader'
});
```